# Deserialize json object to array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, json.net

I have a Json file that is as below and I would like to  create an array of `name` that includes `["h","hg","g","f"]`.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "h",
    "dir": "h",
    "valid": false
  },
  {
    "name": "hg",
    "dir": "fg",
    "valid": false
  },
  {
    "name": "g",
    "dir": "f",
    "valid": false
  },
  {
    "name": "f",
    "dir": "fgh",
    "valid": false
  }
]
```

I have accomplished to get the value of a name, but not an array of all names.

```cs
    dynamic data = JArray.Parse(Var.txt); //get text in json file
    string name = data[0].name; //get name from first part
    string dir = data[0].dir;
    bool valid = data[0].valid;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}",name[0], dir[0], valid); //write
```

Comment: *array of name that includes `["h","hg","f"]`*. How about **g** ?

Comment: Take your JSON, paste into https://app.quicktype.io, paste the given classes back into your project, do `YourChosenRootClassNameOnQT.FromJson(Var.txt).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()`.. and that's about it.. You'd perhaps cache the result of the parse so you could do other queries rather than reparsing every time but..

Comment: And if you need the Console.WriteLine from the code sample, that could be `YourChosenRootClassNameOnQT.FromJson(Var.txt).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", x.Name, x.Dir, x.Valid));` etc but ultimately what you're really saying is you need your json into a structured colelction of objects: that's `YourChosenRootClassNameOnQT.FromJson(Var.txt)` doing that

Comment: Do one thing at a time. First, deserialize json into C# objects. Then, extract the data you want out of it. It's WAY easier to do several simple tasks than a single convoluted one.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new class:

```
public class MyClass {
   
   [JsonProperty("name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("dir")]       
   public string Dir { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty("valid")]       
   public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

And then just use deserialize:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass[]>(myJsonResponse).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you have massive amounts of items in your JSON and don't want to deserialize because you are only and only interested in `name`, you can operate on `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument` too.

Given you have the JSON, maybe after you do a file read from .txt:

```cs
var txtContent = @"[{""name"": ""h"", ""dir"": ""h"", ""valid"": false }, {""name"": ""hg"",""dir"": ""fg"",""valid"": false},{""name"": ""g"",""dir"": ""f"",""valid"": false},{""name"": ""f"",""dir"": ""fgh"",""valid"": false}]"
var data = JsonDocument.Parse(txtContent);
```

Then you can leverage `RootElement.EnumerateArray()`:

```cs
var list = data.RootElement.EnumerateArray().Select(element => element.GetProperty("name").GetString()).ToList();
```

However, mind that this is a weakly-typed approach and if you are planning to use that JSON data further and can afford deserializing, I'd rather go with that too.